# Five-dimensional manifolds fibering over a fixed hyperbolic surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I am aware of the classical work by Smale and Barden computing the diffeomorphism type of smooth simply connected 5-manifolds in D. Barden, [Simply connected five-manifolds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970702), Ann. of Math. (2) 82 (1965), 365–385 and S. Smale, [On the structure of 5-manifolds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970417), Ann. of Math. (2) 75 (1962), 38–46.

Has there been any effort to give invariants for 5-dimensional smooth manifolds fibering over a fixed hyperbolic surface?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say "fibering" do you means as a smooth fiber bundle? Smooth fiber bundles with fiber $F$ and base $B$ are classified by homotopy classes of maps from $B$ to the classifying space $B\mathrm{Diff}(F)$. If you case $F$ is a $3$-manifold so $\mathrm{Diff}(F)$ is somewhat better understood, see  [Hatcher's survey](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff(M)2012.pdf). The following two examples show what challenges exist.

If $F=S^3$, then  by Hatcher's proof of the Smale conjecture, or by recent results of Bamler and Kleiner discussed  [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06197) the group $\mathrm{Diff}(S^3)$ deformation retracts to $O(4)$. Then we just need to give a diffeomorphism classification of the total spaces of linear $S^3$-bundles over the surface $B$. In the orientable case (i.e., when the structure group is $SO(4)$ rather than $O(4)$) such bundles are completely classified  in [Classification of Oriented Sphere Bundles Over a $4$-Complex](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/doldwhit.pdf) by Dold and Whitney, and the bundle is completely determined by its second Stiefel-Whitney class in $H^2(B:\mathbb Z_2)\cong\mathbb Z_2$. One still has to see whether the total spaces are non-diffeomorphic, which is true (Hint: from the long exact sequence of the (pair $5$-disk bundle over $B$, its boundary) note that the inclusion of the boundary is injective on the 2nd cohomology, so the 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class of the disk bundle has nonzero restriction of the boundary iff $w_2\neq 0$. Finally, $w_2$ is a homotopy invariant for closed manifolds, so the two sphere bundles are not even homotopy equivalent).

If $F$ is closed orientable hyperbolic $3$-manifold, then by Gabai's proof of Smale conjecture $\mathrm{Diff}(F)$ deformation retracts to a finite group $G:=\mathrm{Iso}(F)$. This can also be done via Ricci flow (see the above mentioned preprint of Bamler-Kleiner). Thus the bundle is classified by the homotopy classes of maps from $B$ to $BG=K(G,1)$, i.e., by the set of conjugacy classes of homomorphisms from $\pi_1(B)$ to $G$. I am not sure if anyone classified their total spaces up to diffeomorphism, but e.g. if $G=1$, then there is only the trivial bundle.